# Change a boolean value from a list of checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a list that returnsa list of jobs with a boolean set on false, and in my view I want to change it on true. My problem is that the view is not passing the ID back, I can't see why.

At first I was using foreach but after some research I figured out I should use for with IList.

Here is back-end:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = MyRoles.Admin)]
public ActionResult JobsToModerate()
{
    var allJobs = db.Jobs.Where(x => x.isModerated == false).ToList();

    return View(allJobs);
}

[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = MyRoles.Admin)]
public ActionResult JobsToModerate([Bind(Include = "ID,isModerated")] Job job, EditJobViewModel editJob)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var jobs = db.Jobs.Find(editJob.ID);

        if (jobs == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            jobs.ID = editJob.ID;
            jobs.isModerated = editJob.isModerated;
        }

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
    }

    return View();
}
```

My View:

```
@model IList<JobSite3.Models.Job>

@using (Html.BeginForm("JobsToModerate", "Jobs", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })



    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].ID)
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[i].Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[i].isModerated)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].isModerated)
            </td>
        </tr>


      </table>

      <input type="submit" id="btnNew" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    }
}
```

I believe there is a similar problem with solution out there but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model in your view is `IList<Job>` so your POST method needs to match. It needs to be

```
public ActionResult JobsToModerate(List<Job> model)
{
    ....
```

However the code within you method does not make sense for a collection, and its not clear what your `EditJobViewModel` class is. I assume you will want to iterate through each `Job` and update the database

Comment: yep I will mark as answer, I also added  `foreach (var item in job)  {` in my post action to edit my boolean state according to view input. Yea it doesn't make sense because I was lazy and I copy pasted from another action and then I modified for a list instead of a solo element and I got confused at the end.